# Stack Overflow new footer links are erroneous

Tags: bug, status-completed, footer

The new Stack Overflow footer has a couple of wrong links:

1. **data** has https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.stackexchange.com instead of https://data.stackexchange.com/
2. **api** has https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api.stackexchange.com which is not a tag (hope not) and probably should be https://api.stackexchange.com/.

Screenshot:[image: Footer]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

Those links slipped through our testing.

Now fixed.